# Is there a resource to explain how to export photos to a web site, for example like iPhoto to Facebook Export?

Tags: objective-c, plugins, export, iphoto

I am trying to understand the process of exporting from iPhoto to a web site.  This would website would be a content management system.  I have already located the iPhoto SDK for Exporting but cannot get my head around how to change the destination to a web site/service and the process involved.  I am looking for some resource to give me a overall architectural overview.

Comment: You can try uploading using a socket, HTTP is a really easy protocol

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded photos with NSMutableURLRequest. Just add your photo as POST data.

Here's some links that should steer you on the right path:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?POSTMethodANDNSURLRequest

If you really can't figure it out after that, post a comment to this answer and I'll dig up some of my old code.